# Desktop files disappeared suddenly

Tags: linux, desktop

OS - linux lite.

I don't get why all the files in the desktop suddenly disappeared. It is not moved anywhere. I searched through command line and checked trash folder too.

What would be the cause for it? How can I get back my files? In Desktop, most were shortcuts of application and some files there. I need atleast files.

Comment: which linux ? ubuntu ? raspian ? Did you do something special ? system crashed ?

Comment: Linux Lite 2.0.  No I dint do anything.

Comment: My mobile was connected  with the system via connector. But I used to connect mobile with system daily. But today only i got this issue.. So I don't think this would be the cause